# mongodb set object where key value dynamically changes

Tags: mongodb

In a document I have an object called `farms` and inside this object I would like to update key-value pairs in the following mannner. How would I do this?

```
$set:{"farms[${farm._id}]":{name:"a-farm", size:100}
```

the result would look like this(assuming `farm._id = 12345`)

```
farms:{"12345": {name"a-farm", size: 100}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/index.html) and build your key dynamically using dot notation, try:

```
var farm = { _id: 12345 }
var path = "farms." + farm._id;
var documentId = ... // your document id

db.col.update({ _id: documentId  }, { $set: { [path]: { name:"a-farm", size:100 } }  })
```