# Removing an element in a mongoDB array based on the position of element with dynamically defined array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

My question is a combination of:

This question: [Removing the array element in mongoDB based on the position of element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969768/removing-the-array-element-in-mongodb-based-on-the-position-of-element)

And this question: [mongodb set object where key value dynamically changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54283430/mongodb-set-object-where-key-value-dynamically-changes)

I know you can define the field (array) dynamically like this:

```
{ [arrayName]: { <condition> } }
```

But, I then want to remove a certain element in a dynamically defined array by specifying the position (which is also defined dynamically). In other words, the function that processes this query is coming in which two parameters: the array's name and the index of the element to remove.

The options given by [the selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4970050/15547098) were the following:

**Option 1**, does not work (in general), adapted to my case this looks like:

```
{ $pull : { [arrayName] : { $gt: index-1, $lt: index+1 } } }
```

**Option 2**, I cannot use dynamically defined values in field selectors with quotation marks (as far as I am aware):

```
{ $pull : "[arrayName].[index]" }
```

or

```
{ $pull : "[arrayName].$": index }
```

**Option 3**, is different method but can't use it for the same reason:

```
{ $unset: { "[arrayName].[index]": 1 } } // Won't work
{ $pull: { [arrayName]: null } } // Would probably work
```

The only workarounds I can think of right now involve significantly changing the design which would be a shame. Any help is appreciated!

PS: I'm using mongoose as a driver on the latest version as of today (v6.3.5) and MongoDB version 5.0.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Mongo version 4.2+ You can use pipelined updates to achieve this, you can get it done in multiple ways, here is what I consider the easiest two ways:

1. using `$slice` and `$concatArrays` to remove a certain element:

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      [arrayName]: {
        $concatArrays: [
          {
            $slice: [
              `$${arrayName}`,
              index,
            ]
          },
          {
            $slice: [
              `$${arrayName}`,
              index + 1,
              {
                $size: `$${arrayName}`
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UwryRvEmZ0M)

2. using `$filter` and `$zip` to filter out based on index:

```
db.collection.updateOne(
{},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      [arrayName]: {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $filter: {
              input: {
                $zip: {
                  inputs: [
                    {
                      $range: [
                        0,
                        {
                          $size: `$${arrayName}`
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    `$${arrayName}`
                  ]
                }
              },
              cond: {
                $ne: [
                  {
                    "$arrayElemAt": [
                      "$$this",
                      0
                    ]
                  },
                  index
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          in: {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              "$$this",
              1
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Alternatively you can just prepare

Comment: Amazing! They both work perfectly, thank you so much!